# How to find the real problem line in my code with Application Verifier?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, application-verifier

I am now trying to use this Application Verifier debugging tool, but i am stuck, first of all: it breaks the program at a line that is simple variable set line (s = 1; for example)

Secondly, now when i run this program under debugger, my program seems to have changed its behaviour: i am drawing image, and now one of the colors has changed o_O, all those parts of the image that i dont draw on, has changed the color to #CDCDCD when it should be #000000, and i already set the default color to zero, still it becomes to #CDCDCD.

How do i make any sense to this?

Here is the output AV gave me:

```
VERIFIER STOP 00000002: pid 0x8C0: Access violation exception. 

    14873000 : Invalid address causing the exception
    004E422C : Code address executing the invalid access
    0012EB08 : Exception record
    0012EB24 : Context record

AVRF: Noncontinuable verifier stop 00000002 encountered. Terminating process ... 
The program '[2240] test.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741823 (0xc0000001).
```

Comment: `0xCD` is the fill character used by the Microsoft debug runtime to indicate uninitialized memory.

Comment: Hmm, interesting... could it be that my program crashes because Microsoft debug runtime changes my data? any ideas how to know which places it messed up my data? (except that checking all my code memory allocations and making sure i set the data to zero...)

Comment: @Newbie: Never assume the compiler or debugger is "changing your data" and breaking your code. It's your code that's broken, you have an uninitialized variable somewhere.

Comment: I thought my compiler would have noticed me about uninitialized variables, i remember it noticing about those :/ How do i turn on those notifications again?

Comment: @Newbie: It can only warn you about some uninitialized variable usage; it can't diagnose every possible case (for example, I tracked an uninitialized variable _across a network interface_ a few months ago... yeeeaaaaahhhh, talk about fun times).  Basically, you need to find the variable that is uninitialized and work backwards to see where it came from.

Comment: It's always a good idea to set "Warning Level" to "Level 4 (/W4)" and also set "Treat Warnings As Errors" to "Yes (/WX)". You'll find these options in the Project settings under Configuration Properties, C/C++.
This should help you find the uninitialized variable. You should get a C4700 or C4701.

Comment: Nice... 267 warnings found :D This'll take whole day to clean...

Answer (score 1):

Typically when breakpoints are hit like this (via AV or an unhandled exception, etc.) inside a debugger, there is a green arrow pointing to a line of code.  That arrow is pointing to the ***next statement to execute when the thread returns from the current function***.  Perhaps this green arrow is pointing to the line where you wrote "s = 1", but really the offending code is the line above it.  Now I can't see your code so I can't exactly know for sure and I don't have enough rep to post a comment - but this is something that is easy to check the next time the breakpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet that `s` is NOT a "simple" variable. I'm much more likely to believe it's something like this:

```
class Foo;
    int s;
    void Bar() {
        s = 1;
    }
};
```

Sure, it looks like a simple `s=1` statement, but in reality it is a `this->s=1` statement. And if `this` is an invalid pointer, `this->s` isn't a proper variable either.

Comment: nope, it is this: bool var = 0; ... error line: var = 1; as simple as that.

Comment: Global, function local? The point of my statement is that we need to know what kind of variable it is, to know where it lives. From there we might be able to understand the error.

Comment: its defined as global yes, ourside of main() function.